# Adobe Acrobat Pro Dc - How to use get by name command to show all brench at the Model Tree for 3D

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I got sample file and has this command at checkbox javascript

```
var Node2Switch = getAnnots3D(0)[0].context3D.scene.nodes.getByName("9****1().fd********657f723eba029b67a33584da02d48");
```

****** are just for safety :)

How can I find "fd********657f723eba029b67a33584da02d48" part?

I can only view "9****1()" that name and the sub objects and objects nodes at the model tree .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more clear in your question.

Comment: Sorry for that, that was my first question and thanks for edit 

You can see the my sample at the top I need to use getByName command for another pdf and that Pdf's 3D object and I'm using it but I think I'm not fill right or well enough 

I got this idea cause I cannot view the following numbers and letters after the dot.
How can I find or write the full object name?

Thank you for your interest @RogerOliveira

Comment: https://ibb.co/sgnVZCS <br/>
https://ibb.co/mbM0Wxz <br/>
https://ibb.co/vkV7bKg <br/>
@RogerOliveira As you can see I cannot find the object name extension at the model tree.How can I find that long object name?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<this.getAnnots3D(0)[0].context3D.scene.nodes.count; i++) {

  var nd=this.getAnnots3D(0)[0].context3D.scene.nodes.getByIndex(i);

  console.println(nd.name);

}
```

I finally did it thats the code 
Step 1 - Open Pdf and press ctrl + j to open console 
Step 2 - Writte the above-mentioned code to console and press ctrl+enter or numpad enter key 
You can view all the full nodes names of model tree at the console output